# One JSON object into few collection objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having a puzzler here. I have the following collection:

```
var TagsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TagModel,
    parse : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // code to go
        return response;
    }
});
```

Now that fetches the following sample JSON object:

```
{
    id: 10149682, 
    published: "2014-01-13 08:23:00", 
    title: "Title", 
    tags: "tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4"
}
```

now what I want is to insert some code that will re-map the existing response into the following format:

```
[{name: "tag1"},  {name: "tag2"}, {name: "tag3"}, {name: "tag4"}]
```

and load it into the collection. (An important note - using Backbone / Underscore methods - for ex. _.chain / _.reduce etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) you `tags` key:

```
var tags = response.tags.split(',');
```

And [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) the resulting array

```
return _.map(tags, function(tag) {
    return {name: tag};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```
var tags= "tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4";

var newArr = tags.split(',').map(function(tag){ return {name: tag} });
```

**Important**: This works in IE9+ if you need this to run in IE8 or older you need to polufill. You can fine the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)